# osm2pgsql finishes processing without creating vertices_tmp table

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I am using postgresql 9.1 database with posgis installed. I also have pgroute installed on same database. I am trying to use osm2pgsql tool to import data for routing. But osm2pgsql tool finishes processing without creating the vertices_tmp table, the output is like this:

```
Adding ways to database...
Creating topology...
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
#########################
size of streets: 40234
size of splitted ways : 125002
finished
```

After i also try to do this step manually by executing this command:

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

But it gives a similar error like this(with more details):

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 32 at EXECUTE statement
```

Any ideas how i can finish importing data for pgroute? I am using a city database(istanbul) osm file from http://metro.teczno.com .

Answer (score 1):

I am just learning postgres and I just spent 3 hours with the same exact error. In my case I was loading a national roads network shp file for Canada. I fixed it by reimporting the data with simple geometry using the shpfile importer. (there is a checkbox under options, or -S at the commandline). There should be something similar for the OSM importer.

Turns out that when the geom colum type is set to multilinestring st_startpoint will return a null value and break the whole script.

Once the data was re-imported with the geom column set to linestring it ran perfectly.

Comment: i could not find such an option in osm2pgrouting tool, the problem is more likely result of not having vertices_tmp table perhaps i did miss a step while preparing the setup... I tried the virtual machine image from http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html and everything is running perfectly there for the moment. But i still need to fix what went wrong in my installation.